# Код не возвращает данные из JSON файла

Tags: javascript, json, promise

Проходя курс по JS столкнулся с проблемой во время использования Promise вместо обычных callback функций.

Дело в том, что значение из json файла не возвращается от resolve()

```js
let inputRub = document.getElementById('rub'),
    inputUsd = document.getElementById('usd');


function calculate(input){
    input.addEventListener('input', () => {
        function convert() {
            return new Promise (function(resolve, reject) {
                let request = new XMLHttpRequest();

                request.open('GET', 'js/current.json');

                request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');

                request.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status == 200) {
                        resolve()
                    } else {
                        reject()
                    }
                }
                request.send()
            })
        } //End covert

        convert()
            .then(() => {
                let data = JSON.parse(request.response); 
                inputUsd.value = inputRub.value / data.usd;
            })
            .catch(() => inputUsd.value = "Что-то пошло не так!")
    });
}

calculate(inputRub);
```

Ошибок в консоли нет, во вкладке Network возвращает 304
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Слышал проблему, что это происходит из-за того что браузер кэширует данные и не происходит их изменения, но это ни о чём не сказало, так как начав гуглить про то, как убрать кэширование браузером - там речь идёт совсем о других моментах.

Если же добавить

```js
let data = JSON.parse(request.response); 
inputUsd.value = inputRub.value / data.usd;
```

во внутрь функции convert() вместо resolve() - то оно будет нормально конвертировать, но я так понимаю, смысл в том чтобы использовать именно конструкцию внизу

Comment: А вы почему в resolve ничего не передаете? Ошибка происходит скорее всего из-за `JSON.parse(request.response)` т.к. request.response = undefined

Comment: да, я пробовал добавлять request.response в resolve. точно такая же ошибка возникает

Answer (score 0):

Вот так перепишите и должно заработать:

```
request.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status == 200) {
                   resolve(request.response)
          } else {
                   reject(null)
          }
 }
```

А вызов convert вот так:

```
convert().then((resp) => {
                let data = JSON.parse(resp); 
                inputUsd.value = inputRub.value / data.usd;
            })
            .catch(() => inputUsd.value = "Что-то пошло не так!")
    });
```

Comment: К сожалению ничего не изменилось.

Comment: а бэк у вас на чем?

Comment: В качестве базы просто локальный json файл в котором написана просто одна строчка с курсом usd.

Comment: Какой у вас web-сервер? Вообще описание проблемы описано вот в этой статье https://airbrake.io/blog/http-errors/304-not-modified

Comment: Ну я пробовал в vscode с помощью плагина live server и ещё xaamp. И там и там вроде апачи

Comment: У себя в коде сделайте так: `request.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');` и `request.setRequestHeader('cache-control', 'max-age=0');`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100213/discussion-between-4rmr3d1-and-balamutik).